# Como tratar váriavel em bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, cron

Estou com um problema, estou fazendo um script em bash para rodar usando o crontab, que sincroniza meus arquivos do ssd, com o hd e o dropbox.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash -

PC_DIR="~/Programming"
DROP_DIR="~/Dropbox/Programação"

PC_FILES="$(find ${PC_DIR} -follow)"
DROP_FILES="$(find ${DROP_DIR} -follow)"

for FILE1 in "${PC_FILES}"
do
    echo "FILE1=${FILE1}"
    for FILES2 in "${DROP_FILES}"
    do
        echo "FILE2=${FILE2}"
        if [ "${FILE1}" -nt "${FILE2}" ];
        then
            cp "${FILE1}" "${FILE2}"

        elif [ "${FILE1}" -ot ""${FILE2} ];
        then
            cp "${FILE2}" "${FILE1}"
        fi
    done
done
```

O problema com o script é que ele trata as variáveis "FILEx" como um grande bloco de texto com várias funções de quebra de linha ('\n') ex:

```
FILE1=~/Programming
~/Programming/C++
~/Programming/C++/teste.cpp
~/Programming/C++/test.cpp
```

Pórem, para fazer os testes de 'NewerThan' e 'OlderThan', preciso conseguir olhar cada linha como um diretório diferente, e não como um grande bloco, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Gabriel, espreita o comando `rsync` dentro da pŕopria máquina ou remoto. Exemplo:  `rsync -l -turv dir/  maquina.remota:dir/`

Comment: Gabriel, parece-me que o teu algoritmo copia o ficheiro mais novo para cima dos outros todos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está em **"${PC_FILES}"** e **"${DROP_FILES}"**. Com as aspas, basicamente está dizendo ao algoritmo para ele capturar tudo como string e jogar na variável `FILE1` e `FILE2` respectivamente.

A solução para seu código é fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#!/bin/bash

PC_DIR="after"
DROP_DIR="bkp"

PC_FILES="$(find ${PC_DIR} -follow)"
DROP_FILES="$(find ${DROP_DIR} -follow)"

IFS=$'\n'

for FILE1 in ${PC_FILES}
do
    echo "FILE1=${FILE1}"
    for FILE2 in ${DROP_FILES}
    do
        echo "FILE2=${FILE2}"
        if [ "${FILE1}" -nt "${FILE2}" ];
        then
           echo "Copia ${FILE1} para ${FILE2}"

        elif [ "${FILE1}" -ot ""${FILE2} ];
        then
            echo "Copia ${FILE2} para ${FILE1}"
        fi
    done
done
```

Há uma outra maneira, também, de ler a saída do find (ou qualquer outro comando) que é utilizar o comando **[read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)** juntamente com o comando **[while](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html)**

```
#!/bin/bash -

PC_DIR="after"
DROP_DIR="bkp"

PC_FILES="$(find ${PC_DIR} -follow)"
DROP_FILES="$(find ${DROP_DIR} -follow)"

IFS="\\"

while read FILE1; do

        while read FILE2; do

                if [ "${FILE1}" -nt "${FILE2}" ]; then
                    echo -e "Copia ${FILE1} para ${FILE2}\n"

                elif [ "${FILE1}" -ot ""${FILE2} ]; then
                    echo -e "Copia ${FILE2} para ${FILE1}\n"
                fi

        done <<< ${DROP_FILES}

done <<< ${PC_FILES}
```

Eu partirculamente prefiro o **while**¹

> Observe que adicione uma linha a mais, o **[IFS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)**. Essa variável nada mais é que um "separador".
>   Ela basicamente informa ao bash como reconhecer os campos, limites, etc.

¹ Para saber a diferença entre while/for, recomendo a leitura de *[Reading lines from a file with bash: for vs. while](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/reading-lines-from-a-file-with-bash-for-vs-while)*

Comment: a resposta apontou e corrigiu o problema perguntado (+1) mas alerto para que o algoritmo está um pouco estranho... (copia o ficheiro mais recente para cima dos outros todos)